# Web cameras fails under 14.04 with usb2

Tags: 14.04, usb, webcam, camera

system:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
RAM:8Gb
XUbuntu 14.04 (all latest updates)
kernel: 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
motherboard: P8H67-M PRO (BIOS upgraded to version 3902 of 11/30/2012)
```

Tried two different cams. One unknown:

```
idVendor=093a, idProduct=2468
Product: CIF Single Chip     
Pixart Imaging Inc.
using gspca_main: pac207-2.14.0
```

Another is genuine Intel(R) C330 (yes, VERY old, but working just perfect):

```
idVendor=0733, idProduct=0401
using gspca_main: spca501-2.14.0
```

Both worked fine on Spring-2014 on same PC with 13.10, when I used both for Skype and Google Hangouts. Now they will be recognized only after plugged into USB3 port, but fail with "not enough bandwidth" with USB2 ports. After connected via USB2 port to VirtualBoxed WinXP they also fails with "usb 2-1.6: usbfs: usb_submit_urb returned -28" messages.

More... Under Linux (since 10.04) C330 distorts the colors. Compare these two snapshots (capture settings are default. Sorry, not enough reputation to insert images into the question):

Taken from Linux with latest VLC
[colors are distorted](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-8XbqRuTIydE/VLs7AcbC4vI/AAAAAAAAuYw/SYKu4oa9HZc/w640-h480-no/vlcsnap-2015-01-18-14h17m58s473.png)

Taken from WinXP on the same PC running in VirtualBox with latest VLC
[colors are normal](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-IHezc4mFGcQ/VLs7Bys8yPI/AAAAAAAAuY4/ijI9pFhFE7k/w640-h480-no/vlcsnap-2015-01-18-15h13m58s164.png)

Skype allows to select these cameras, but does not display anything. Google Chrome in Hangouts disallows usage of videodevices at all. Google Talk plugin for Firefox allows to choose the camera, but displays nothing with no errors in syslog.

What the hell, Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch!  Probably not enough people use these any more and some compiler flags got changed between versions.  The only thing you can do is [file a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

(sorry to be the harbinger of bad news)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)